# MUI Table border-spacing

Tags: material-ui

I am using material Ui v5.8.4 in reactjs, but I can't find a way to add border spacing to the table component. For a typical HTML CSS environment, the style is as bellow

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 15px;
}
```

how can I achieve the same in material UI tables?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured all I needed to include was sx props to the Table component with the following properties.

```
sx={{
          borderCollapse: "separate",
          borderSpacing: "0px 10px"
    }}
```